# Как из php сделать XMLHttpRequest запрос?

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest

Можно ли через php сделать Что-то вроде XMLHttpRequest на сайт, который имеет https и SSL. Код:

```
<?
$r = new HTTPRequest('http://example.com'); // or https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id=210700286&v=5.52
echo $r->DownloadToString(); 

class HTTPRequest 
{ 
var $_fp;        // HTTP socket 
var $_url;        // full URL 
var $_host;        // HTTP host 
var $_protocol;    // protocol (HTTP/HTTPS) 
var $_uri;        // request URI 
var $_port;        // port 

// scan url 
function _scan_url() 
{ 
    $req = $this->_url; 

    $pos = strpos($req, '://'); 
    $this->_protocol = strtolower(substr($req, 0, $pos)); 

    $req = substr($req, $pos+3); 
    $pos = strpos($req, '/'); 
    if($pos === false) 
        $pos = strlen($req); 
    $host = substr($req, 0, $pos); 

    if(strpos($host, ':') !== false) 
    { 
        list($this->_host, $this->_port) = explode(':', $host); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $this->_host = $host; 
        $this->_port = ($this->_protocol == 'https') ? 443 : 80; 
    } 

    $this->_uri = substr($req, $pos); 
    if($this->_uri == '') 
        $this->_uri = '/'; 
} 

// constructor 
function HTTPRequest($url) 
{ 
    $this->_url = $url; 
    $this->_scan_url(); 
} 

// download URL to string 
function DownloadToString() 
{ 
    $crlf = "\r\n"; 

    // generate request 
    $req = 'GET ' . $this->_uri . ' HTTP/1.0' . $crlf 
        .    'Host: ' . $this->_host . $crlf 
        .    $crlf; 

    // fetch 
    $this->_fp = fsockopen(($this->_protocol == 'https' ? 'ssl://' : '') . $this->_host, $this->_port); 
    fwrite($this->_fp, $req); 
    while(is_resource($this->_fp) && $this->_fp && !feof($this->_fp)) 
        $response .= fread($this->_fp, 1024); 
    fclose($this->_fp); 

    // split header and body 
    $pos = strpos($response, $crlf . $crlf); 
    if($pos === false) 
        return($response); 
    $header = substr($response, 0, $pos); 
    $body = substr($response, $pos + 2 * strlen($crlf)); 

    // parse headers 
    $headers = array(); 
    $lines = explode($crlf, $header); 
    foreach($lines as $line) 
        if(($pos = strpos($line, ':')) !== false) 
            $headers[strtolower(trim(substr($line, 0, $pos)))] = trim(substr($line, $pos+1)); 

    // redirection? 
    if(isset($headers['location'])) 
    { 
        $http = new HTTPRequest($headers['location']); 
        return($http->DownloadToString($http)); 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        return($body); 
    } 
} 
} 

?>
```

При исполнении выдает ошибку:
Warning: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://api.vk.com:443 (Connection refused) in ...
Может ошибка из-за использования бесплатного хостинга а может из-за какого-то запрета со стороны сервера VK.

Comment: а вас чем не устраивают `file_get_contents` или `cURL`, зачем сокеты?

Comment: ответ - никак. `XMLHttpRequest` это запрос из браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Легче лёгкого:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```

Удачи вам в изучении PHP и [мануал в помощь](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file-get-contents.php).